# Redirecting in react js class based components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting up a **signup page** in react js using the ***class component***. I want to redirect to the home page after login. Since the react-router-dom has upgraded to v6.0 the ***{withRouter}*** functionality is no more available. Any idea how can I do this?

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'react-router-dom'

1. Import Navigate

```js
 import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

2. then just run this method

```js
  ... 
  myFunction() { 
    this.props.history.push("/home"); 
  } 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is working for the functional components. but I want for the class component. any idea?

Comment: you can use this
`this.props.history.push('/home')`